# gallery thumbnail

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I accidentally deleted the contents of .thumbnails folder in DCIM in sdcard. After deleting it I am unable to access MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID however MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA is having all the images. How do I regenerate thumbnails in the .thumbnails folder to get the details of MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID?

I initially had the idea that the gallery app in Android generates thumbnails in the .thumbnails folder so what I did was clear the cache of gallery app. Unmounted the sdcard and mounted it again in the hope that .thumbnail folder will have all the thumbnails when I relaunch the app
I am using Infocus M535 phone

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the .thumbnail folder is autogenerated periodically.
If the clearing cache didnt work, did you try clearing the data for the gallery app? This ideally shouldnt actually erase your photos and videos, but on the safer side do take the backup.

Alternatively, if that doesnt work and if you want a quick fix, then go Play Store and download great alternatives to the stock gallery such as QuickPic.